# Using VoiceOver from Python

Tags: python, macos, accessibility

Is there are way to post notifications to VoiceOver (and other screen-readers) on Mac from a Python program? Something like:

`UIAccessibilityPostNotification` *or* `NSAccessibilityPostNotification`

but the freedom to output any custom string?

Comment: I’m not sure whether you’ve looked into these already, but my first two thoughts are to use [PyObjC](https://www.pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/) or [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: @icktoofay I did and am hoping to use them as well. But the APIs I found were available to Cocoa apps. I don't have "real" cocoa UI elements to use these functions from.